# Adding images to select menu using option value

Tags: jquery, html, css

While there are many similar questions, I could not find one that fitted best and offered a working solution in my case. After spending couple of hours and failing at every try, I've decided to seek help here. What I'm trying to achieve and my limitations:

1. Add images to a select list option based on the option value.
2. I cannot make any changes to the select list html structure, its automatically created in the app and I don't have access to make any changes to it. Meaning that I cannot add `data-class` or `data-value` attributes to option as shown in many examples.

After reading all the different solutions, I came up with the following. But the following code gives me `$(...).selectmenu is not a function` error.

```js
$("#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type").selectmenu().on('change', function(ev) {
    $(this).attr('class', '').addClass($(this).children(':selected').val());
});
```

```css
#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type option[value="app_1_column_layout"] { background-image: url('images/onecol.png'; } 
#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type option[value="app_2_column_layout"] { background-image: url('images/twocol.png'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type">
  <option value="app_1_column_layout">App: 1 Column Layout</option>
  <option value="app_2_column_layout">App: 2 Column Layout</option>
</select>
```

You can see it on the website [here](http://chakraco.club/node/add/application), in case you are wondering.

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change  Also that may be incorrect way to provide the event binding for the `selectmenu`

Comment: `selectmenu` is not a core jQuery method.  It is a jQuery UI method, so you will need to include UI after your jQuery core include, and before your custom logic, for it to work

Comment: Hi @Taplar I was just editing my message when you commented, I realized that `;` was a typo there, I fixed it but ended up with another error. I'm not sure if this is the right way to tackle my issue at all now.

Comment: I have jQuery included on my website and using it in different places.

Comment: Again, please read my third comment with regards to `selectmenu` not existing

Comment: I can as well share the website link, http://chakraco.club/node/add/application

Comment: `selectmenu` did not exist in jQuery UI 1.10.  It was added in 1.11

Comment: I cannot update it to jQuery 1.11 at this point. In this case, would there be another way to add images to select menu?

Comment: You cannot add images to a `<select>`, and you cannot use `selectmenu` without upgrading.  So if you need images on a visual select element, you will need to find another plugin.  And that's not `jQuery 1.11`, that's `jQuery UI 1.11` which is independent from the core version, unless otherwise stated in the documentation.  Updating UI doesn't always mean you have to update Core as well.

Comment: This website is built upon Drupal, I'm not familiar with it, trying to make minor improvements. I was thinking, maybe I could add class to each option.

Comment: I'm not sure what adding a class to an option will do with regards to the native `<select>` and `<option>` tags not being able to show images.

Comment: I think I found a way, this post turned out to be irrelevant but thank you very much Tapar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that is with the use of select2 plugin and implement it with this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/zuyqk6j4/):

```
function loadPic (opt) {
if (!opt.id) return opt.text;             
var optimage = $(opt.element).attr('data-image'); 
optimage = ((optimage != '') && (optimage != null) && (optimage != 'null') && 
(typeof(optimage) != "undefined")) ? optimage : 'images/noprofile.jpg';
return $('<span><img src="' + optimage + '" class="optimg" /> ' + $(opt.element).text() + '</span>');
};

$('select').select2({
    templateResult: loadPic,
    templateSelection: loadPic
});
```

Comment: I ended up using `jQuery Selectric`, but I will keep select2 plugin in mind for future use too, thank you!